# I know the max decimal place will be 18, if I user ini_set('precision', 18), it changes the number output again

Tags: php, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

```
`ini_set('precision', 18);
$number2 = 5.00025051541321;
echo ($number2);

Output: 5.00025051541321019`
```

What can be the issue and if someone help me to solve that.

Comment: With 15 digits, `ini_set('precision', 15)` will provide that exact number. With precision 18, you will get further digits. Read up on [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: If you're wondering why, when you set the precision to 18, it doesn't display it as 5.00025051541321000, see the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004).  If you're wondering something else, please clarify.

Comment: Short answer: With less than infinite precision, floating point can't represent every number. And in binary, 5.00025051541321 is one of the numbers that can't be represented. The closest you can get is a binary number that, when converted back to decimal, looks like 5.000250515413210194992643664591014385223388671875 — or, when rounded to 18 significant digits, 5.00025051541321019.